# Javascript - how to use variables to replace the existing code at run time

Tags: javascript

I have the below code and i want to replace the code at run time depending on a variable value, how do i achieve this using javascript. Also please ignore the FormA , animate etc as they are used by kony mobile.

```
//desired out put inside the run time code. 
    FormA.ItemFlexContainer0.animate

    //index has a value of 0 for now. 
    var index = 0;
    var ItemFlexContainerString = "ItemFlexContainer"+index;
    FormA.ItemFlexContainerString.animate

    Error :- Type Error null is not an object
```

Since ItemFlexContainerString doesnt exist it will throw the error.

Comment: in my case this worked and the answer mentioned in the existing question would not work, FormCart["ItemFlexContainer"+index].animate , the array should have double quotes with index appended to it as written.

Answer (score 0):

You need bracket notation:

```
FormA[ItemFlexContainerString]animate
```